# Diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Assume $A$ is a positive definite matrix, and $B$ is a matrix with zero row sum.

Does matrix $A$ exist such that $AB$ is strictly diagonally dominant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can a matrix with row sums $0$ be strictly diagonally dominant?

Comment: B is zero row sum, but I am wondering, can we easily find a positive definite matrix that makes C=AB a strictly diagonally dominant?

Comment: You don't understand.  If $B$ has all row sums $0$, then so does $AB$.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. A computational error had caused I keep getting a non-zero row sums.